# sed to replace with backspace

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed, tcsh

I have `trail.txt`, which contains `spice` netlist. Now I want to replace all expanded parameters to one line only i.e. remove `+` and append that line to previous line.

### trail.txt

```
data
+ net06706 net06707
+ net221 net222 net223 
m1 net10 rwl vdda vss nch l="l1pg+0.005u" w=w1pg+0.105u 
m0 vdda rwld net10 vss nch l="l1pg+0.005u" w=w1pg+0.105u
```

### (Desired) trail.txt

```
data net06706 net06707 net221 net222 net223 
m1 net10 rwl vdda vss nch l="l1pg+0.005u" w=w1pg+0.105u 
m0 vdda rwld net10 vss nch l="l1pg+0.005u" w=w1pg+0.105u
```

### Command

```
sed -e 's/^+/\b/g' trail.txt
```

I tried to repalce `+` with `backspace` but its not working out. Is there any alternate way to work on this? Are there any other alternatives available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use a backspace approach - however you could do something like

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n+/ /;ta' -e 'P;D' trail.txt
```

See [Famous Sed One-Liners Explained, Part I: File Spacing, Numbering and Text Conversion and Substitution](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/), **40. Append a line to the previous if it starts with an equal sign "="** (with the obvious substitution of `+` for `=`).

Comment: I think I need to modify the above command for `tcsh`; 

currently it shows error as N: Event not found

Comment: Yes in tcsh you may need to escape the ! (even though it is protected by single-quotes) i.e. `'$\!N;s/\n+/ /;ta'`

Comment: Now it works perfectly

Comment: Can I convert this `sed` to `sed -i` inline editor mode?
I tried this `sed -i :a -e '$\!N;s/\n+/ /;ta' -i 'P;D' trail.txt`

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, GNU `awk`

```
awk -vRS='\\n\\+?' '{ORS=RT == "\n+"? "":RT; print}' trail.txt
data net06706 net06707 net221 net222 net223
m1 net10 rwl vdda vss nch l="l1pg+0.005u" w=w1pg+0.105u
m0 vdda rwld net10 vss nch l="l1pg+0.005u" w=w1pg+0.105u
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ideas, since it'll be a bit tricky with sed:

```
perl -00 -pe 's/\n\+\s*/ /g' file
```

```
awk '
    {
        if (/^\+/) 
            sub(/^\+[[:blank:]]*/, " ", $0)
        else 
            if (NR > 1) print ""
        printf "%s", $0
    } 
    END {print ""}
' file
```

Comment: Or to provide your script as onliner `awk '!/^\+/&&NR!=1{print""}{sub(/^\+/,"");printf$0}END{print""}' file`

Comment: Don't use `printf` without a format specifier in case the string contains `%` -- `echo "foo%sbar" | awk '{printf $0}'`

Answer (score 0):

Use Perl instead of sed:

```
perl -ne 'chomp; print "\n" unless s/^\+// or 1 == $.; print }{ print "\n"'
```

`chomp` removes newline. `$.` is the input line number.

Answer (score 0):

`GNU sed` allows to do not use `perl` for such simple task:

```
sed -z 's/\n+//g' trail.txt
```

Comment: what is meant by `-z` ? I am using `tcsh` and `man sed` or `sed help` has nothing listed for `-z`

Comment: @JigarGandhi This is problem `sed` version not shell. **-z**, **--null-data** *separate lines by NUL characters* Try `sed --version` - I have `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Comment: `GNU sed version 4.1.5`

Answer (score -1):

```
sed  's/.$//'

sed  's/.$//g'
```

This should work.
Worked for me

Comment: this doesn't do what OP asked.